# How to display thumbnails from harvested items in DSpace?

Tags: xslt-1.0, dspace

I am trying to display the thumbnails from harvested items. The settings I have for the harvesting options is **Harvest metadata and references to bitstreams (requires ORE support)**. When looking for the code on how DSpace displays the filenames and file sizes of the bitstreams of the harvested items in simple view, I found that in https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6.1/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl#L375-L378

```
<!-- Special case for handling ORE resource maps stored as DSpace bitstreams -->
<xsl:when test="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM" />
</xsl:when>
```

and for the full item record view in https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6.1/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl#L81-L84.

```
<!-- Special case for handling ORE resource maps stored as DSpace bitstreams -->
<xsl:when test="./mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="./mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']" mode="itemDetailView-DIM" />
</xsl:when>
```

So it seems that code found in `item-view.xsl` is calling the template match found in [`ORE.xsl`](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6.1/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/ORE.xsl).

Now, looking at a sample `mets.xml` file of a harvested item specifically in `//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']`, we can see that it is referencing the `ORE.xml` in `/bitstream/handle/10862/3360/ORE.xml`.

```
<mets:fileSec>
  <mets:fileGrp USE="ORE">
    <mets:file GROUPID="group_file_f148a8ad-b7ad-49fe-8b4b-0d3893d2c351" CHECKSUM="7afebcfcf393395503377219395e3926" MIMETYPE="text/xml" SIZE="4137" ID="file_f148a8ad-b7ad-49fe-8b4b-0d3893d2c351" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5">
      <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="/bitstream/handle/10862/3360/ORE.xml?sequence=1&isAllowed=y" xlink:type="locator" xlink:title="ORE.xml"/>
    </mets:file>
  </mets:fileGrp>
</mets:fileSec>
```

Based on the template match found in `ORE.xsl`, we can see that the file names and file size was generated from this code:

```
<xsl:template match="mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM">
    <xsl:variable name="AtomMapURL" select="concat('cocoon:/',substring-after(mets:file/mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']//@*[local-name(.)='href'],$context-path))"/>
    <div class="item-page-field-wrapper table">
        <h5>
            <i18n:text>xmlui.dri2xhtml.METS-1.0.item-files-viewOpen</i18n:text>
        </h5>

        <xsl:for-each select="document($AtomMapURL)/atom:entry/atom:link[@rel='http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/aggregates']">
            <xsl:variable name="link_href" select="@href"/>
            <xsl:if test="/atom:entry/oreatom:triples/rdf:Description[@rdf:about=$link_href][dcterms:description='ORIGINAL']
                        or not(/atom:entry/oreatom:triples/rdf:Description[@rdf:about=$link_href])">
                <xsl:call-template name="itemSummaryView-DIM-file-section-entry">
                    <xsl:with-param name="href" select="@href" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="mimetype" select="@type" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="label-1" select="'title'" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="label-2" select="'title'" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="title" select="@title" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="label" select="@title" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="size" select="@length" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Viewing the `/bitstream/handle/10862/3360/ORE.xml`, we can see that aside from the `ORIGINAL` bundle, the `TEXT` and `THUMBNAIL` bundles were also captured when it was harvested.

```
<atom:link href="https://repository.seafdec.org.ph/bitstream/10862/152/1/ediblecrustacea.pdf" length="2310365" rel="http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/aggregates" title="ediblecrustacea.pdf" type="application/pdf"/>
<atom:link href="https://repository.seafdec.org.ph/bitstream/10862/152/4/edible-crust-errata.pdf" length="177699" rel="http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/aggregates" title="edible-crust-errata.pdf" type="application/pdf"/>
<oreatom:triples>
  <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:about="http://hdl.handle.net/10862/152/ore.xml#atom">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.dspace.org/objectModel/DSpaceItem"/>
    <dcterms:modified>2011-06-07T06:45:26Z</dcterms:modified>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:about="https://repository.seafdec.org.ph/bitstream/10862/152/35/edible-crust-errata.pdf.txt">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.dspace.org/objectModel/DSpaceBitstream"/>
    <dcterms:description>TEXT</dcterms:description>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:about="https://repository.seafdec.org.ph/bitstream/10862/152/36/ediblecrustacea.pdf.txt">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.dspace.org/objectModel/DSpaceBitstream"/>
    <dcterms:description>TEXT</dcterms:description>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:about="https://repository.seafdec.org.ph/bitstream/10862/152/1/ediblecrustacea.pdf">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.dspace.org/objectModel/DSpaceBitstream"/>
    <dcterms:description>ORIGINAL</dcterms:description>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:about="https://repository.seafdec.org.ph/bitstream/10862/152/4/edible-crust-errata.pdf">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.dspace.org/objectModel/DSpaceBitstream"/>
    <dcterms:description>ORIGINAL</dcterms:description>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:about="https://repository.seafdec.org.ph/bitstream/10862/152/32/ediblecrustacea.pdf.jpg">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.dspace.org/objectModel/DSpaceBitstream"/>
    <dcterms:description>THUMBNAIL</dcterms:description>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:about="https://repository.seafdec.org.ph/bitstream/10862/152/33/edible-crust-errata.pdf.jpg">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.dspace.org/objectModel/DSpaceBitstream"/>
    <dcterms:description>THUMBNAIL</dcterms:description>
  </rdf:Description>
</oreatom:triples>
```

Now my goal is to capture and reuse the url found in `/atom:entry/oreatom:triples/rdf:Description[@rdf:about][dcterms:description='THUMBNAIL']` and make it as the `src` of the thumbnail found in the code for the [`itemSummaryView-DIM-thumnail`](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6.1/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl#L168-L207) and [`mets:file`](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/eb4d56201a6e398dc23c91e6e1fd1ab87de58054/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl#L533-L656)template, sort of hotlinking to the original thumbnail. By the way, the **Files in this item** view is not that nice anyway so...

[image: files]

With regards to the displaying of thumbnail in simple view, I'm thinking of having an `<xsl:when test="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']">` in the  `itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail` template ie:

```
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']">
                <xsl:variable name="src">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="/mets:METS/mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']/mets:file[@GROUPID=../../mets:fileGrp[@USE='CONTENT']/mets:file[@GROUPID=../../mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']/mets:file/@GROUPID][1]/@GROUPID]">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                    select="/mets:METS/mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']/mets:file[@GROUPID=../../mets:fileGrp[@USE='CONTENT']/mets:file[@GROUPID=../../mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']/mets:file/@GROUPID][1]/@GROUPID]/mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']/@xlink:href"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of
                                    select="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']/mets:file/mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']/@xlink:href"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <!-- Checking if Thumbnail is restricted and if so, show a restricted image --> 
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($src,'isAllowed=n')"/>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <img class="img-thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail">
                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$src"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </img>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <img class="img-thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail">
                    <xsl:attribute name="data-src">
                        <xsl:text>holder.js/100%x</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$thumbnail.maxheight"/>
                        <xsl:text>/text:No Thumbnail</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </img>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

My problem now is that I don't know how to reference the url for the thumbnail in the `ORE.xml` file. I noticed also that the name and file size were extracted from the `/atom:entry/atom:link[@rel='http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/aggregates']` based from the `ORE.xsl` code above.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Here's what I did:
I modify the `[dspace]/config/crosswalks/oai/metadataFormats/ore.xsl` of the source server such that it will expose the thumbnails in the `<atom:link rel="http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/aggregates">` portion of `OAI` output when using `ore` as the metadata format, but I have to clean the cache of oai and do a full reimport of OAI in the source server. Also, I have to reset and import the harvest from the harvesting server to include the new generated `ORE.xml` files. The modification I did was to change line number 67 of `ore.xsl` from

```
<xsl:if test="doc:field[@name='name']/text() = 'ORIGINAL'">
```

into:

```
<xsl:if test="doc:field[@name='name']/text() = 'ORIGINAL' or doc:field[@name='name']/text() = 'THUMBNAIL'">
```

Then in `item-view.xsl`, I included this line in the `<xsl:template name="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail">`:

Then, in `[dspace]/webapps/xmlui/themes/Mirage2/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/ORE.xsl` I include these lines:

```
<xsl:template match="mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail">
    <xsl:variable name="AtomMapURL" select="concat('cocoon:/',substring-after(mets:file/mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']//@*[local-name(.)='href'],$context-path))"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document($AtomMapURL)/atom:entry/atom:link[@rel='http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/aggregates']" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="atom:link[@rel='http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/aggregates']" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail">
    <xsl:variable name="link_href" select="@href"/>
    <xsl:if test="/atom:entry/oreatom:triples/rdf:Description[@rdf:about=$link_href][dcterms:description='THUMBNAIL' and position() = 1]
                or not(/atom:entry/oreatom:triples/rdf:Description[@rdf:about=$link_href])">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This worked except that in cases where there are multiple thumbnails in the source item, it will also show more than one thumbnails even though I have in my test condition `<xsl:if test="/atom:entry/oreatom:triples/rdf:Description[@rdf:about=$link_href][dcterms:description='THUMBNAIL' and position() = 1] or not(/atom:entry/oreatom:triples/rdf:Description[@rdf:about=$link_href])">`. See screenshot below:

[image]

Also, I would rather not modify the `ore.xsl` in the crosswalk directory of the source server hence this post: [Extract attribute value if child node contains this text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52584066/1919069)

**UPDATE 2 - Thumbnail is now displayed in simple item view**

What I did:

In `<xsl:template name="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail">`, I inserted the code below after line# 195:

```
<xsl:when test="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail" />
</xsl:when>
```

Then, I added this templates in `ORE.xsl`:

```
<xsl:template match="mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail">
    <xsl:variable name="AtomMapURL" select="concat('cocoon:/',substring-after(mets:file/mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']//@*[local-name(.)='href'],$context-path))"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document($AtomMapURL)/atom:entry/oreatom:triples" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="oreatom:triples" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail">
    <xsl:if test="/atom:entry/oreatom:triples/rdf:Description[dcterms:description='THUMBNAIL']
                or not(/atom:entry/oreatom:triples/rdf:Description)">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail">
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="rdf:Description[boolean(@rdf:about) and
                   .//dcterms:description[. = 'THUMBNAIL']][1]/@rdf:about"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

My harvested item is now displaying the thumbnail in item summary view:
[image]

It would really be great if I can also make the thumbnails display in the item list and search results but for now, I can't figure out how to match and select the thumbnail url. I don't know how to reference them from within the `<xsl:template match="mets:fileSec" mode="artifact-preview">` template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my future reference, this is what I have made to show the thumbnails for harvested items.

This answer is based on DSpace 5x Mirage2 Theme but it can also be applied to DSpace 6x Mirage2.

In `item-view.xsl`, locate the `<xsl:template name="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail">` block and then insert this code:

```
<xsl:when test="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail" />
</xsl:when>
```

before the `<xsl:otherwise>` block. Complete template block below:

```
<xsl:template name="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']">
                <xsl:variable name="src">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="/mets:METS/mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']/mets:file[@GROUPID=../../mets:fileGrp[@USE='CONTENT']/mets:file[@GROUPID=../../mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']/mets:file/@GROUPID][1]/@GROUPID]">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                    select="/mets:METS/mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']/mets:file[@GROUPID=../../mets:fileGrp[@USE='CONTENT']/mets:file[@GROUPID=../../mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']/mets:file/@GROUPID][1]/@GROUPID]/mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']/@xlink:href"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of
                                    select="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='THUMBNAIL']/mets:file/mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']/@xlink:href"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <img alt="Thumbnail">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$src"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </img>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <img alt="Thumbnail">
                    <xsl:attribute name="data-src">
                        <xsl:text>holder.js/100%x</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$thumbnail.maxheight"/>
                        <xsl:text>/text:No Thumbnail</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </img>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Then edit `ORE.xsl` and insert the code below just before the `</xsl:stylesheet>` ending tag.

```
<xsl:template match="mets:fileGrp[@USE='ORE']" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail">
    <xsl:variable name="AtomMapURL" select="concat('cocoon:/',substring-after(mets:file/mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']//@*[local-name(.)='href'],$context-path))"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document($AtomMapURL)/atom:entry/oreatom:triples" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="oreatom:triples" mode="itemSummaryView-DIM-thumbnail">
    <xsl:if test="/atom:entry/oreatom:triples/rdf:Description[dcterms:description='THUMBNAIL']
            or not(/atom:entry/oreatom:triples/rdf:Description)">
        <img alt="Thumbnail" class="img-responsive">
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="rdf:Description[boolean(@rdf:about) and
               .//dcterms:description[. = 'THUMBNAIL']][1]/@rdf:about"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

To show the thumbnails in item list, edit `common.xsl` and locate this code:

```
<xsl:text>?sections=dmdSec,fileSec&amp;fileGrpTypes=THUMBNAIL</xsl:text>
```

and change it to:

```
<xsl:text>?sections=dmdSec,fileSec&amp;fileGrpTypes=THUMBNAIL,ORE</xsl:text>
```

To show thumbnails in search results, locate that same line of code above in the file `discovery.xsl` found under `[dspace-src]/dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage2/xsl/aspect/discovery` directory and modify it just like in the `common.xsl` file.

All file modifications in this answer are made under the `[dspace-src]dspace/modules` directory.

Example of this code in action can be found here: [SEAFDEC External Publications](http://repository.seafdec.org/20.500.12066/5768)